# Replacing headphone jack in Motorola Moto Z2 Play

Tags: audio, hardware, headphone-jack

I'd like to know, if it is possible to replace malfunctioning (actually: dead) headphone jack in Motorola Moto Z2 Play? I would like to do this in an repair shop (not myself), if this is possible at all.

I mean "possible" in terms of hardware. If it isn't for example an irreplaceable part of mainboard or if something else does not make such repair impossible or too expensive.

If this isn't possible or would be too expensive, what other options do I have? Is purchasing and using any [microUSB-to-jack adapter](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/316KD%2BO4upL._SX466_.jpg) the only option?

The only, of course, next to replacing the whole phone. But since audio-jack is the only problem in otherwise working and useful phone then I'd like to avoid this option as much as possible.

Comment: Just watch the repair tutorial yourself: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Motorola+Moto+Z2+Play+Audio+Jack+Replacement/103357

Comment: make sure it's actually a hardware failure and not just permission issue in settings. i think it's not worth it to open the phone just for headphone jack if there is a risk to damage display. bluetooth headphones is another alternative

Comment: @Robert Thanks for pointing this out. I'd say that your comment is a valid answer. You could write something like "Yes, this is certainly possible, not only in repair shop, you can do this yourself" + link. Due to my limited skills, I'd like to do this in a repair shop, but for some reason I'm getting responses that such replacement is not possible, so it may turn over that I will be forced to do this myself. Thank you.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for pointing this out. However I am more than certain that this is a hardware problem, since I started to hear only on one of the ear phones and soon for none as I was doing nothing (just listening, screen turned off). And then it turned out that jack is simply very very loose. I can move my cable around and at some weird position I can again hear on one earphone and and some other position -- at second one.